# Is it possible to share hard drives on an Apache server?

Tags: apache, http

I just finished installing Apache on windows 8 on an old desktop I had. I can access the index.html page from the internet using my global IP.

I was thinking of a use for it, and I like the idea of being able to read/write files to the desktop via the server. Is this possible? I don't know much about this kind of stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Symbolic link may be the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to allow read-only access to all your files and directories as long as the process owner Apache is running as has access to it. To write files you'll probably need something else like samba or ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WebDAV - it's the intersection between file sharing and a web server.

However, you should consider very carefully the security implications when sharing your desktop - a hacker may be able to take control of your machine by changing the "Daily backup" shortcut to point to "Install Spyware".